# Search for a string in an array and store the row number in which it occurs?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, search

I've seen a few questions similar to this, but none are quite the same!

I have a rather large array with **no two values repeated**.
I need to search through the array for a certain string and **store the row number** where the string is located.

This will be performed several times, so if possible, the "fastest" way would be appreciated!

For example
Array:

```
   1  2  3
   4  5  6
   7  8  9
```

Say I want to look for "8".  The code should search through the matrix, find that it's on the 3rd row and store a "2" into a variable (or "3" depending on whether option base 1 is included or not).

In my case, **the value(s) I'm looking for will only occur on a single column**, so I don't need to search the entire array.

Thanks so much.

EDIT:
Sorry for my lack of ediquette! This is my first post.  Here is what I have so far:

```
col=3
For row = 1 to 50
  if searchterm = Matrix(row,col).value Then
    searchrow=row
    exit for
  end if
Next row
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: (firstly I'm new at this, so bear with me! This is my first ever post!) I guess that's my problem.  I don't know where to start.  Everything I've seen so far is just looking for a certain value or is searching for the number of instances.  I'm extremely inexperienced with VBA and I'm not sure where to begin.  Here's what I have so far: 'col = 3
    For row = 1 To 50
        If searchterm = Matrix(row, col) Then
        searchrow = row
    Next row'

Comment: Code should be edited into your original question, it is too hard to read as a comment.

Comment: Bleh, that looks terrible.  I edited the post so you can see the code I'm using!  Thanks.

Comment: You will need an End If for one...

Comment: Try this instead of your For loop `MsgBox Application.Match(searchterm, Application.Index(matrix, col), 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are intrinsically fast.  This function will return an array of indices.  The return value will be empty if the lookup value isn't found.

### Usage

```
indices = getValueIndices(8, DataArray)

If not isEmpty(indices) then
    x = indices(0)
    y = indices(1)
End if
```

### Function

```
Function getValueIndices(Value As Variant, DataArray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim is2d As Boolean
    Dim v As Variant
    x = LBound(DataArray, 1)

    On Error Resume Next
    is2d = UBound(DataArray, 2)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If is2d Then y = LBound(DataArray, 2)

    For Each v In DataArray
        If v = Value Then
            If is2d Then
                getValueIndices = Array(x, y)
            Else
                getValueIndices = Array(x)
            End If
            Exit Function
        End If
        x = x + 1
        If x > UBound(DataArray, 1) Then
            x = LBound(DataArray, 1)
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

### Test

```
Sub Test()
    Dim DataArray As Variant

    'Test 1D Array - Base 0
    DataArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
    Debug.Print "Test 1D Array - Base 0: "; getValueIndices(8, DataArray)(0)

    'Test 2D Array - Base 1
    DataArray = [{1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9}]
    Debug.Print "Test 2D Array - Base 1:"; getValueIndices(8, DataArray)(0), getValueIndices(8, DataArray)(1)

    'Test 2D Array - Base 0
    ReDim DataArray(0 To 2, 0 To 2)
    DataArray(0, 0) = 1: DataArray(0, 1) = 2: DataArray(0, 2) = 3
    DataArray(1, 0) = 4: DataArray(1, 1) = 5: DataArray(1, 2) = 6
    DataArray(2, 0) = 7: DataArray(2, 1) = 7: DataArray(2, 2) = 8
    Debug.Print "Test 2D Array - Base 0: "; getValueIndices(8, DataArray)(0), getValueIndices(8, DataArray)(1)
    Debug.Print "Test IsEmpty with Bad Value: "; IsEmpty(getValueIndices(100, DataArray))

End Sub
```

### Results

[image]